# Removing trailing and leading spaces

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to filter out commas and spaces from file input.
I am returning a line of input(example below and passing that line to a method which is filtering out the commas and leading and trailing spaces)

```
John Paul Claurigh, Craig Megan, Bob a’ Chores
```

should filter to three separate strings in the an array.

```
John Paul Claurigh
Craig Megan
Bob a’ Chores
```

My problem is not getting rid of the commas but eliminating the leading and trailing spaces.

```
public void listConverter(String list){
String[] array=listConverter.split(",");
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    addSubject(array[i]);
}
```

Can I use the split method to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces ?

Comment: `.split(\\s*,\\s*);` look for a comma with or without surrounding whitespace. The regex will be greedy and will swallow all whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
String[] array = s.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Which means split by any number (0..n) spaces before or after comma (,).

Output:

```
<John Paul Claurigh>
<Craig Megan>
<Bob a’ Chores>
```

Comment: @Neuron, you can't use trim() on the split() method. SMA's answer is correct to what was asked. OP wants to split as well as taking care of leading/trailing spaces in a single statement. Quoting - _split method to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces_

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct, just use [trim()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm) to remove the leading/ending spaces

```
public void listConverter(String list){
String[] array=listConverter.split(",");
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    addSubject(array[i].trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple split with a space after comma is more than enough

```
String s = "John Paul Claurigh, Craig Megan, Bob a’ Chores";
String[]tokens = s.split(", ");//note the space after comma.
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

Comment: This does not remove all leading and tailing spaces as was asked in the question. It just works on the single example given in the question..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public void listConverter(String list){
String[] array=listConverter.split("\\s*,\\s*");
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    addSubject(array[i]);
}
```

It will split on comma with or without any leading/trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

A java 8 rendition

```
    String fileInput = "John Paul Claurigh,   Craig Megan    ,    Bob a’ Chores   ";

    List<String> namesList = Pattern.compile(",\\s")
            .splitAsStream(fileInput)
            .map(name -> name.trim())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


    namesList.forEach(name -> System.out.println("NAME: " + name));
```

OUTPUT

```
NAME: John Paul Claurigh
NAME: Craig Megan
NAME: Bob a’ Chores
```